# A question about acyclic fixed point set of torus action on acyclic space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Oliver claims in the article (A proof of the Conner conjecture) that any
action of a torus on a paracompact $
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
$-acyclic space of finite cohomological dimension with finitely many orbit
types has $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
$-acyclic fixed-point set: This follows from next theorem. This theorem is
taken from W. Y. Hsiang's book, Cohomology Theory of Topological
Transformation Groups (page 40)

**Theorem:** Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and $X$ be a $G$-space,
paracompact and with finite cohomological dimension. Let $S\subset H^{\ast
}\left( B_{G}\right) $ be a multiplicative system and $s\in S$. Then the
localized restriction homomorphism

$
S^{-1}H_{G}^{\ast }\left( X\right) \longrightarrow S^{-1}H_{G}^{\ast }\left(
X^{s}\right) 
$

is an isomorphism.

If $X$ consists of only finite orbit types, then

$
S^{-1}H_{G}^{\ast }\left( X\right) \longrightarrow S^{-1}H_{G}^{\ast }\left(
X^{S}\right) 
$

is also an isomorphism.

But I have not seen any evidence to show that this conclusion can be
obtained from this theorem. Probably Oliver means the following proposition
derived from the theorem above in the same book (page 45)

Let $G=T^{r}$ (resp. $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{p}^{r}$) and $k=%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
$ (resp. $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{p}$). Then it is well known that
\begin{eqnarray*}
H^{\ast }\left( B_{G};k\right)  &=&k\left[ t_{1},t_{2},\cdots ,t_{r}\right] 
\text{, }\deg t_{j}=2\text{ (resp. }1\text{) when }G=T^{r}\text{ (resp. }%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{2}^{r}\text{) }k=%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211a} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Q}
%EndExpansion
\text{ (resp. }%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{2}\text{)} \\
H^{\ast }\left( B_{G};k\right)  &=&k\left[ t_{1},t_{2},\cdots ,t_{r}\right]
\otimes \Lambda \left[ v_{1},v_{2},\cdots ,v_{r}\right] \text{, }\deg v_{j}=1%
\text{, }t_{j}=\beta \left( v_{j}\right) \text{ when }G=%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{p}^{r}\text{) }k=%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{p}\text{ and }p\neq 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

In both cases, we shall denote the polynomial part by $R$, i.e. $R=k\left[
t_{1},t_{2},\cdots ,t_{r}\right] $ and set $S=R-\left\{ 0\right\} $ which is
clearly a multiplicative systen lying in the center of $H^{\ast }\left(
B_{G};k\right) $.

**Proposition: (A. Borel)** Let $G=T^{r}$ or $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
_{p}^{r}$, $X$ be a paracompact $G$-space with finite cohomological
dimension, and $F=F\left( G,X\right) $ be the fixed point set. Then the
following localized restriction homomorphism

$
S^{-1}H_{G}^{\ast }\left( X;k\right) \longrightarrow S^{-1}H_{G}^{\ast
}\left( F;k\right) =H^{\ast }\left( F;k\right) \otimes _{k}S^{-1}H^{\ast
}\left( B_{G};k\right) 
$

is an isomorphism.

I don't think the claim is true for the coefficient $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2124} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{Z}
%EndExpansion
$.